# Reading data returned from stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure that returns a table (or dataset or view or whatever it's called, it returns the result of a `select`). I use entity framework and I'd expect it to treat the stored proc like a table by creating an entity. When I add the proc to the entity schema, it's added but no class is generated (nothing appears on the schema or in the intellisense).

I do not want to use this dataset solution that looks ugly and unoptimised:

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_ProjetsVoxco");
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(
    Settings.Default.ConnectionStringTransit);
SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
sa.Fill(dataSet);
```

I've found a line that seems to be very neat:

```
var x = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>("sp_ProjetsVoxco");
```

But since entity framework did not generate a class, I'm not really sure what to do with the `T`.

Comment: Did you try to create entity class manually (as POCO for example)?

Comment: Do you already have the Store procedure created in your Database or you trying to do all from code?

Comment: I've not created a class manually. The Stored proc is already in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that you have your `edmx` file and you are now trying to add a Store Procedure that you already have created in the Database.

1 - You should add your Store Procedure that by adding it just like any other table using the **Update Model from database** option, this will make EF to know about a SP. (Because I already have my SP I'm showing the `Refresh` tab, but you will see your SP's in `Add` tab if you didn't add them yet)

[image]

2 - Import a function

[image]

3 - Give it a **name** and create a new **Complex Type**

[image]

4 - Click **OK** and use the new method name

```
public IEnumerable<mySPMethodCallName_Result> ListAllServiceLogsFromSP(decimal clientId)
{
    var r = from sp in db.sp_ListServiceLogsByClientId(clientId)
            select sp;

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding stored procedure to the model is not enough. You must also add [function import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx). Function import is mapping of the stored procedure to method in your context (the method should be generated for you). In this mapping you can either map result to existing entity, complex type or define a new complex type.

`ExecuteStoreQuery` has nothing to do with imported stored procedure. It is used to execute SQL directly (= mostly avoiding EF) and `T` must be your custom type which has public settable properties with same names as result set returned from your stored procedure.